# Alarmservice not working

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-alarms

In my application I need to run some code every midnight. This is the first time I am working on alarm service and Searched the internet for some snippets and examples.

Below is my code and its not working as expected, please help my pointing out my mistake:

**SET A REPEATING ALARM**

```
private static void initiateMidnightAlarm(Context context, AlarmManager alarmManager) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    PendingIntent midnightIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0,
            new Intent("com.alarms.MidnightProcess"), 0);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, midnightIntent);
}
```

**DECLARE THE RECEIVER IN THE MANIFEST:**

```
<receiver
    android:name=".receivers.MidnightProcessReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.alarms.MidnightProcess"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

**RECEIVER CODE:**

```
public class MidnightProcessReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public MidnightProcessReceiver() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        processMidnightLogic(context);
    }

    public static void processMidnightLogic(Context context) {
        Toast.makeText(context,"MidnightProcessReceiver",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.appname">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

    <permission
        android:name="com.appname.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="com.appname.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>

    <application
        android:name=".BaseApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
        .
        .
        ..
        ..
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name=".receivers.MidnightProcessReceiver"
            android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.alarms.MidnightProcess"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver
            android:name=".receivers.OnBootReceiver"
            android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Please help!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The Receiver in never invoked. Nothing happens, as if no alarm is set

Comment: PendingIntent midnightIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0,
            new Intent("com.alarms.MidnightProcess"), 0);              - Are you referncing the correct package name here.

Comment: No, should this be a package name? I thought it should be any unique string that is been Broadcast.

Comment: If still the problem exists, could you update your question with the full manifest file.

Comment: @MikeM. It dint help.

Comment: @codePG I am posting my manifest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need to fire an implicit broadcast, rather than start a Service, you're retrieving the wrong type of PendingIntent. Change:

```
PendingIntent midnightIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0,
        new Intent("com.alarms.MidnightProcess"), 0);
```

to:

```
PendingIntent midnightIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,
        new Intent("com.alarms.MidnightProcess"), 0);
```